# Shopify cart attributes lost when checkout form submit redirects to login or guest checkout screen

Tags: checkout, shopify, cart

We are seeing cart attributes get lost for some orders and have tracked it back to the case when the "Accounts are optional" setting for checkout enabled and the cart form is submitted for checkout. If the user has not seen the login or optionally checkout as guest screen, they are redirected here first. At this stage, whatever new cart attributes were submitted in the POST intended for checkout are not preserved and are lost when the user continues to the checkout screens.

Here is the evidence we gathered...

1) The value of /cart.js before cart form is submitted for checkout confirming there are no attributes currently saved with the cart ... http://cl.ly/PF62

2) While viewing our cart page, we use jQuery to confirm the attributes that will be added at cart update or checkout POSTs:

```
> var inputs = jQuery('form#cartform').serializeArray();
> for (var x=0;x<inputs.length;x++) {
      console.log(inputs[x].name + ': ' + inputs[x].value);
  }
> updates[201564942]: 1
  note: 
  attributes[delivery_note]: 
  attributes[referrer_dropdown]: Choose One
  attributes[referrer_text]: 
  attributes[speaker]: 
  attributes[search_keywords]: 
  attributes[backordered-haven-82-inch-solid-wood-media-console-espresso-on-oak]: Ships in: about 6 weeks
  attributes[backordered-po-haven-82-inch-solid-wood-media-console-espresso-on-oak]: None
```

3) Before trying normal checkout, jQuery.clone() the form, and change it's action to submit to a http://requestb.in url to verify the posted elements. Here is the result confirming all of the input items are POSTed properly ... http://cl.ly/PG9h

4) Now submit the form normally and end up on the accounts/login view ... http://cl.ly/PEzJ

5) Now check /cart.js again ... no changes saved to attributes ... http://cl.ly/PF4w

6) Now click checkout as guest and end up on first screen of checkout.

7) Go BACK to /cart page

8) Click Checkout again, this time there is no redirect and we go straight to checkout.

9) Now check /cart.js again ... http://cl.ly/PFS3

10) EUREKA, the cart attributes are saved this time.

Even though as a Shopify developer, this problem could be worked around by forcing a cart update POST in the background before POSTing to checkout, this seems to be a bug that needs to be fixed. A little surprising there seems to be no chatter about this elsewhere on the forums or here on SO.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be reproduced on my end. I used a fresh install of the New Standard [theme](http://themes.shopify.com/themes/new-standard/styles/slate) , I added the following to the cart form in cart.liquid:

```
<input type="hidden" name="attributes[someValue]" value="Hello" />
```

I went through a first order as guest, I was presented with the Log in or Continue as Guest screen and checked out as a guest. I completed the order (used the Bogus Gateway, maybe that matters?).

On the order details screen, I can see my cart [attribute](http://take.ms/IiDDh) (Interesting observation, the key someValue was renamed to somevalue (all smallcase).)

So that works: the cart attribute was not lost for going through the Log in or Continue as Guest screen.

After that, I went through a second order. When you have checked out as a guest not long before, you're not asked again: clicking on the checkout button on the cart page brings you directly to page 1 of the checkout, bypassing the Log in or Continue as Guest screen.

On the order details screen of that second order, I can see my cart [attribute as well](http://take.ms/IHGDX) .

Comment: Thanks Caroline, looks like we tracked this down for this customer to a separate .js file that was being loaded at the theme.liquid level for cart template only. It must have been put there by the original developer since it specifically targeted the cart attributes that were being lost when orders were created. It's job was to wipe the cart attributes containing a specific word in the key name every time the cart page loaded. I'm still not quite sure how this script would get executed when you POST/submit the cart form to the /cart url with the checkout parameter passed.

Comment: To elaborate, the .js isn't rogue, I understand why it's there, but what doesn't make sense yet is how that script could affect the cart attributes being removed when the cartform is POST/submitted with checkout parameter. Any ideas?